# Win32Exception in Unity3D when trying to run an Android application

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, oculus

I'm trying to run an Android application through Unity3D and keep getting the following error (below the Build settings window):
[image]

I've tried a few fixes that I found online. For example, I set the JAVA_HOME variable here:

[image]

Also I have 3 Android SDK's on my machine and have copied zipalign.exe from their build-tools to tools.

None of these seemed to have worked for me and I haven't been able to find any other suggestions online. Can anybody help me?

I really appreciate any advice, thanks.

EDIT:
More detailed error message
[image]

Comment: did you try running javac from the command line? most probably you need to add some folders to PATH and set JAVA_HOME to a jdk installation and not a jre installation

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it just means that Unity had a brain fart, and there's a few things you can do to try to fix it.

Here's a list in increasing order of gut wrenching pain

1. Copy aapt.exe from Your_SDK_Path/build-tools/{ADT_VERSION_HERE}/ to Your_SDK_Path/tools/
2. Update Android SDK Manager, ADT and everything else you can
3. Reinstall Unity
4. Reinstall Android SDKs
5. Reinstall OS

I, unfortunately had to go all the way to Step 5 before getting mine fixed. Hopefully, you don't go past Step 3

EDIT: Just FYI, I think your path might be incorrect as well. The System variable is called "PATH", and should point to jdk{version}/bin

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this in a few minutes.